# Running an SQL query in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

Very new to Azure and SQL here. I have an API that I have set to write data to an SQL database in Azure. I realized that I made an error in my data mapping in my API (data going to the wrong column).

I wrote an SQL query in the Azure portal to transfer values in the incorrect column to the correct one. I also fixed my API.

Here's my question - does that SQL query execute just the once? Or will it repeat the command every time new data is added to my SQL database?

The code here probably isn't necessary, but here it is below.

```
UPDATE ExTable
SET email_1 = email2
WHERE from LIKE 'email@email.com';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need an insert TRIGGER similar to [insert trigger described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Any time new data is added(inserted) to your SQL database, the trigger will execute.

Comment: Thanks David. Tell me if this is incorrect. a TRIGGER will update the data every time there is new data. However, my UPDATE will only update the data once? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Your UPDATE (or whatever kind of sql query) will run only once.  If you run it again, it will run again only once.